# What muscles are targeted by these different variations of pull-ups: standard, chin-ups, and the neutral or parallel close grip pull-up?

Tags: muscle, pull-ups, muscle-groups, chin-ups

What muscles or muscle groups are targeted by these different variations of pull-ups: 1.) [standard](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Pull-up_%28exercise%29#List_of_some_variations) (overhanded), 2.) [chin-ups](http://www.flickr.com/photos/theogeo/2476503127/) (underhanded), and 3.) the neutral or parallel close grip pull-out (thumb is nearest the body - can done in an equipment similar to the '[Iron Gym](https://startpage.com/do/search?cat=web&cmd=process_search&language=english&engine0=v1all&query=iron%20gym&x=0&y=0)')? What are the differences in the muscles these pull-up variations target?

Illustrations of the neutral or parallel close grip pull-out:

[image: Source: theblondeleadingtheblind.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/ironmike.jpg]

[image: Source: asseenontv-wholesale.com/images/fitness/iron_gym_1.jpg]

I also would specifically like to know if the modified chin-up as illustrated above, target different muscles compared to a standard pull-up or a standard chin-up? Or does it target similar muscles to one of the two?

Context and reason for question: I would like to know which pull-up variation targets which muscles, so I could use that variation in my workouts and try to focus on a certain muscle. E.g. If my biceps need work (which I do), then I could choose an optimal pull-up variation to use.

I'm also interested in learning what muscles the neutral or parallel close grip pull-up targets (I don't get good results on either Wikipedia or Google), as it is a pull-up variation that can be done in the equipment I use (similar to the 'Iron Gym' equipment).

Comment: Any reason why you'd like to know? Because simply listing a bunch of muscles isn't really useful

Comment: So what goal are you trying to accomplish that requires such information? Then ask how to accomplish the goal and ask for the answer to explain why or how it works the way it works.

Comment: I think the comments have to do with how advanced the user is. If it is a beginner in pull-ups that uses the bar, the fine division of muscle groups matters less than if it is an advanced user. Is it you in one of the pictures?

Comment: @Galaticninja, you have an earlier question about shoulder problems when doing pull ups, are these questions related?

Comment: @IvoFlipse, JohnP and others: I would like to know which pull-up variation targets which muscles, so I could use that variation in my workouts and try to focus on a certain muscle. E.g. If my biceps need work (which I do), then from the current answers it seems that I might want to do chin-ups, instead of standard pull-ups as it seems to target the biceps more.

Comment: @JohnP, IvoFlipse and others: I'm also interested in learning what muscles the modified pull-up (which is actually named the 'parallel close grip pull-up' according to Physical Fitness SE user, Sancho) targets (I don't get good results on either Wikipedia or Google), as it is a pull-up variation that can be done in the equipment I use (similar to the 'Iron Gym' equipment). 

I'm new to both pull-ups and the posting content requirements for this site, so apologies for the confusion. I will edit my question to add further info.

Comment: @fredob I just found those pictures from searching Google/Yahoo/Bing image search. It is not me or anyone I know personally. The sources of the images are listed as the image description (alternative text). As for my earlier post also related to pull-ups, it is not directly related. That issue has now been resolved. Although, I am still using the same equipment (similar to the 'Iron Gym') to do pull-ups or chin-ups.

Comment: You are probably best served by varying and using all possible variations (including grip width). Yes, each variation uses slightly different muscles, but it is better to be well-rounded and that means all variations should be considered.

Comment: This is a [duplicate question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/513/1771), but I think the older one should be merged with this one, because both question and answers are better stated here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common wisdom is that the chin up (supinated grip) targets the biceps. It also appears to target the pectoralis major. The pull up targets the lower trapezius more. [Source](http://www.mikereinold.com/2011/02/pull-up-or-chin-up-which-is-better.html)

Ellington Darden also says the chin up better targets the lats because the involvement of the biceps means the arms won't give out as quickly as the pull up, allowing the back to get worked.

As for the neutral grip pull up, the best I've been able to find explaining why some people have a much easier time with it than the even chin up (despite that the chin up recruits the bicep more than the neutral grip) is from [Mark Rippetoe](http://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/archive/index.php/t-25782.html) that it has a better mechanical advantage.

> Stef points out that the main advantage is probably mechanical: a neutral grip results in a chest position during the movement much closer to the bar, i.e. a shorter moment arm between shoulder and grip. She is much smarter than I am, and possibly pays closer attention to pullup mechanics.

Also, both supination and pronation of the hands involve various forearm muscles which would be held in isometric contraction while the upper arm and back muscles get to go between concentric and eccentric contraction. So depending on the isometric strength of your forearm muscles, they might reach failure before the upper arm or (much less likely) back muscles do.
[Explanation of contraction terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_contraction)

Comment: If the person doesn't even know what muscles are used in this exercise, what makes you think they will know what supinated grip means? While your answer makes sense to me, it's going to be Greek to anyone that is asking what muscles are used. While I admire your polysyllabic tendencies, the target audience and their level of understanding should be considered when phrasing an answer.

Comment: @JohnP Downvoting an answer that addresses the question completely and has a source because the correct words are used? That's pretty rough, and not very useful, I think. How about editing the answer to clarify instead.

Comment: You do realise that the links I provided include the definition of supinated and pronated grips, right? Because you do follow links before deciding whether to upvote or downvote, right?

Comment: And isometric, eccentric, concentric? If you're going to use the technical terms for someone that very probably has a very limited to no understanding of physiology and muscle references, it should be explained what they are. An answer they can't understand is just as bad as no answer at all. While I understand what you mean, I don't think the OP would.

Comment: JohnP, you can always just post a better answer, then. If this is the way Robin wants to answer the question, he's obviously free to do so.

Comment: I have no problem with the answer, per se. I just don't think that it would be useful to the original poster couched in the verbiage that it is. I will add a spurious edit to remove my downvote since everyone feels so strongly about it.

Comment: @JohnP Some of the terms are indeed new to me, but we all have to start somewhere and this is a good learning exercise, so I think it is a good answer. I already have some idea of what a supinated or pronated grip is, in terms of pull-ups (underhand and overhand, respectively) from reading its Wikipedia article. As for isometric, eccentric, concentric, etc., your edit to the Wikipedia article is useful, and I'll read that. If I have more questions, I can always ask again on Physical Fitness SE, right? =)

Comment: A quote from Rip's thread would get my upvote. :)

Answer (score 6):

The modified version that you are asking about it known as the "parallel close grip pull-up".

The main target of all of these is the [latissimus dorsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latissimus_dorsi_muscle).

The additional muscles worked during the **chin-up** and **parallel close grip pull-up** are the [brachialis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachialis_muscle), [brachioradialis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachioradialis), [teres major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teres_major_muscle), posterior [deltoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_muscle), [rhomboids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhomboid_muscles), [levator scapulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levator_scapulae_muscle), lower [trapezius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezius_muscle), middle trapezius, *sternal [pectoralis major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectoralis_major_muscle)*, [pectoralis minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectoralis_minor_muscle), with the *[biceps brachii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biceps)* and the long head of the [triceps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triceps_brachii_muscle) as dynamic stabilizers. (References: [here](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWUnderhandChinup.html) and [here](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWCloseGripChinup.html).)

The additional muscles worked during the **pull-up** are the, brachialis, brachioradialis, *biceps brachii*, teres major, posterior deltoid, *[infraspinatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infraspinatus_muscle)*, *[teres minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teres_minor_muscle)*, rhomboids, levator scapulae, lower trapezius, middle trapezius, pectoralis minor, with the long head of the triceps as a dynamic stabilizer. (Reference: [here](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWPullup.html).)

The differences between the exercises are italicized.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the name of that pull-up variation. I have edited that into my question.

Answer (score 0):

Neutral grip pull ups are the easiest, the upper body just happens to be stronger at pulling with neutral grips. Which is the same reason you are able to row more weight with a dumbbell than with a barbell.

Probably this has something to do with the arms as the long head of the tricep the brachioradialis, brachialis and biceps are all put together in a balanced position where they can output as much force as possible while allowing for greater ranges of motion.

On the other hand chin ups just put more emphasis on the bicep while pull ups work more the brachioradialis.

And for some reason chin ups get harder the more advanced you become, any beginner will feel chin ups as being way easier than pull ups but the situation turns the other way around as they gain experience and muscle mass.

Answer (score -1):

All is good, but stop saying that the pectoral major is being worked at any pull up exercise. Pecs work ALWAYS as pushing muscles, never as pulling muscles.

Comment: All muscles "pull", none push.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21068680 - I will let this stand as an answer, as it is flat out wrong and might disappear as a comment. Take a look at the study cited for amount of muscle activation in both pullups and chinups. It is a study on effectiveness of a product, but the base activation remained the same both with and without the product.

Comment: To wit: the primary function of the pec major is flexion and adduction of the humerus. Both of these are part of pullups. Is it the primary mover? No. Is it *a* mover? Most definitely.

Comment: Once again, there is a basic misunderstanding of how muscles work.
Muscles move the body towards directions.
The pecs, the triceps and the anterior and middle deltoids push objects away from the core, and the core away from objects.
This their ONLY function.
If they get worked in other exercises it's only in their function as stabilizer muscles. But then you'll have to add the abs and the glutes, and almost any muscle in the body, baring perhaps the gastrocnemius muscle.